# C#.net / Visual Studio - connection to Oracle with Wallet issues

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

Switching to using an Oracle Wallet. I have verified that I can connect via SQL developer and programmatically via .NET PowerShell using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (both Core and Framework). I'm trying to not install Oracle Client and just use extended connection strings.

This works in PowerShell:

```
           Add-Type -Path "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
            $connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = XXXl )(PORT = 2484))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = XXX)));User ID=XXX;Password=XXX!;Wallet_Location=c:\Users\XX\Documents\XX\wallet_v5;"
            $con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connection_string)
            $con.Open()
```

I'm having an issue connecting to the same database with the wallet via C#:
Here is a simple console app.

```
            using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
        //OracleConfiguration.TnsAdmin = @"c:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\wallet_v5";
        OracleConfiguration.WalletLocation = @"(SOURCE = (METHOD = file)(METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY=c:\Users\XX\wallet_v5)))";
        OracleConfiguration.SqlNetWalletOverride = false;
        OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "(tcps)";
        OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add("V2SLCPRD", "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=V2SLCPRD)))");
        OracleConfiguration.StatementCacheSize = 25;
        OracleConfiguration.SelfTuning = false;
        OracleConfiguration.BindByName = true;
        OracleConfiguration.CommandTimeout = 60;
        OracleConfiguration.FetchSize = 1024 * 1024;
        OracleConfiguration.SendBufferSize = 8192;
        OracleConfiguration.DisableOOB = true;
        OracleConfiguration.TraceOption = 1;
        OracleConfiguration.TraceFileLocation = @"C:\RBI";
        OracleConfiguration.TraceLevel = 7;
        OracleConnection orclCon = null;
        try
        {
            orclCon = new OracleConnection("User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;data source=V2SLCPRD");
            orclCon.Open();
            OracleCommand orclCmd = orclCon.CreateCommand();
            orclCmd.CommandText = "select * from wf_employees where rownum <= 10 ";
            OracleDataReader rdr = orclCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
                Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + rdr.GetString(0));
        
            Console.ReadLine();
            rdr.Dispose();
            orclCmd.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != orclCon)
                orclCon.Close();
        }
```

Here is the Call Stack:

```
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
      HResult=0x80004005
      Message=Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string
      Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
      StackTrace:
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
       at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
       at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in XXX:line 21
    
      This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(int)
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection.this[int].get(int)
        OracleInternal.Network.TcpsTransportAdapter.Negotiate(OracleInternal.Network.ConnectionOption)
        OracleInternal.Network.TcpsTransportAdapter.ConnectIterate()
        OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.ConnectViaCO(OracleInternal.Network.ConnectionOption, OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution)
    
    Inner Exception 1:
    NetworkException: Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string
    
    Inner Exception 2:
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
```

Comment: You should focus on one problem at a time. Fixing two IDEs and your app all in one question is too much. And don't copy around DLLs. .NET uses NuGet package manager for consuming libraries, so do that instead.

Comment: Fair.  I just wanted to show that I has having issues with ODP.Net.  For now we can focus on how I'm able to connect with Powershell and not with C#

Comment: The stack trace you provided doesn't match the source code provided. Please make sure that the source code you show us generates the exception you show us.

Comment: It was.  I changed main body of the question.  To help simplify it.  Gave entire source and Call Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my C#.net core console app to work/connect with oracle wallet using an older NuGet package 2.18.180.  I don't know why the older version works vs the latest version yet.

Comment: After working with the Alex from Oracle .dot team.  Oracle created Bug 35852518 for this.

Comment: What is the situation now?  Will the latest oracle nuget package work with a wallet?